# How to know which programs are using my dedicated GPU

Tags: graphics, 19.10, amd-graphics

In Windows, there is a GPU section in the task manager which shows which processes are using the GPU, but in the Ubuntu System Monitor there is no such column, (I even looked into the System Monitor Preferences and it had some other options there, but nothing resembling the GPU).

I was facing some issues with my graphics card and which is why I wanted to know this, hope that someone can help me.

I'm using Ubuntu 19.10 btw.

Comment: Nobody is using the discrete GPU if you don't set it manually. So relax, no processes are using it.

Comment: If you are using a nvidia GPU, then `nvidia-smi` should tell you the processes which are consuming your GPU memory.

Comment: @Pilot6 Okayy so only by using the Launch using Dedicated Graphiscs card option in the right click drop down will they use the GPU right?

Comment: @Adupa any idea about AMD?

Comment: Running programs with `DRI_PRIME=1` will use AMD. Maybe the dropdown does the same. I can't check.

Comment: For ATI/AMD GPUs running the old Catalyst driver, `aticonfig --odgc` should fetch the clock rates, and `aticonfig --odgt` should fetch the temperature data. I'm not familiar with AMDGPU-Pro, but a similar tool should exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nvidia-smi` to list all the processes which are using nvidia gpu.

Comment: This is just a repeat of what was already said in the question. Also no one said the OP was using Nvidia.